# Been getting WebResource.axd 404 errors and have ran out of options

Tags: iis, web-config, http-status-code-404, httphandler, webresource.axd

I posted this yesterday with no response so I'm gonna try again. I've been getting these same 3 `WebResource.axd` 404 errors for over a week in my ASP.NET Web Form. I know 2 have to deal with Images and 1 has to deal with JavaScript but don't know where else to go. I've tried adding:

```
<add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True"></add>
```

to my `handlers` in `web.config`, but gives me a 500 error. If I put it in `httphandlers`, my site runs but nothing gets fixed.

I've tried embedding different images and `js` files and referencing them in my `AssemblyInfo` but no luck. I checked all of my CSS files to make sure every image is getting called correctly and there isn't any confusion. I'm seriously out of options at this point. I've taken stuff in and out of my `web.config` over and over, tried changing my IIS, checking all of my references, etc. etc.

Does anybody have any kind of advice or just a direction to go in?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/407954/how-to-diagnose-a-500-internal-server-error-on-iis-7-5-when-nothing-is-written-t)

Basically create a Failed Request rule and continue from there to see what is exactly happening.

Sometimes 500 means your web.config syntax is wrong. Try if your XML syntax is correct.